# Laravel 5.3 - HasMany Relationship not working with Join statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to retrieve symbols with their comments using hasMany in laravel 5.3

**Symbol.php**

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

**Comment.php**

```
public function symbol() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Symbol');
}
```

---

when I run:

```
$symbols = Symbol::with('comments')->paginate(100);
```

I get the correct output (lists all symbols with their comments)

```
@foreach ($symbols as $s)
    {{ $s->name }}
    @foreach ($s->comments as $c)
         {{ $c->body }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

but when I add a join to the statement:

```
$symbols = Symbol::with('comments')
    ->join('ranks', 'symbols.id', '=', 'ranks.symbol_id')
    ->join('prices', 'symbols.id', '=', 'prices.symbol_id')
    ->paginate(100);
```

The foreach loop has no comments for every symbol. Any idea why the join would be causing this?

Comment: Why not add those as a relation as well?

Comment: "Any idea why the join would be causing this" - I guess the `id` of Symbol is overwriten by the id of rank or price. The solution would depend on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think this was what was wrong. When I added a select that only included symbols.id it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are doing joins like this, attributes with the same names will be overwritten if not selected. So select the attributes you need for your code, and nothing else. As shown below.

```
$symbols = Symbol::with('comments')
    ->join('ranks', 'symbols.id', '=', 'ranks.symbol_id')
    ->join('prices', 'symbols.id', '=', 'prices.symbol_id')
    ->select('symbols.*', 'ranks.importantAttribute', 'prices.importantAttribute')
    ->paginate(100);
```

Basicly i think your ids are being overwritten, by the two joins because they also have id fields, i have had a similar problem doing joins, and it breaks relations if the id is overwritten.

And you have to be carefull, all fields who shares names can be overwritten and parsed wrong into the models.